# Is NRVO valid with exception throwing in body?

Tags: c++, copy-elision, nrvo

I am looking to understand the limitations of NRVO in C++. Would a function with an initial named declaration and a single return be optimised for NRVO and elide `T val`, even though the function `myFunc()` has a throwing potential?

```cpp
T myFunc(bool toThrow) {
    T val;

    if (toThrow) {
        throw std::exception();
    }

    // Do other things here.

    return val;
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? Did the compiler use NRVO? If it did, then it probably can.

Comment: I guess it depends on what `T` actually is.

Comment: @Zereges I would have thought the same thing but I couldn't find make Clang *not* use NRVO, even for a type with side-effects in both constructor and destructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested a few versions of your code on [C++ Insights](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPGV4Y2VwdGlvbj4KCmNsYXNzIFQKewpwdWJsaWM6CiAgaW50IGFiYzsKfTsKClQgbXlGdW5jKGJvb2wgdG9UaHJvdykgewogICAgVCB2YWx7IDUgfTsKCiAgCWlmICh0b1Rocm93KSB7CiAgICAgICAgdGhyb3cgc3RkOjpleGNlcHRpb24oKTsKICAgIH0KICAgIC8vIERvIG90aGVyIHRoaW5ncyBoZXJlLgoJdmFsID0geyA3IH07CgogICAgcmV0dXJuIHZhbDsKfQ==&insightsOptions=cpp14&std=cpp14&rev=1.0) and [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cexception%3E%0A%0Aclass+T%0A%7B%0Apublic:%0A++int+abc%5B500%5D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0AT+myFunc(bool+toThrow)+%7B%0A++++T+val%7B+5+%7D%3B%0A%0A++%09if+(toThrow)+%7B%0A++++++++throw+std::exception()%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++//+Do+other+things+here.%0A%09val+%3D+%7B+7+%7D%3B%0A%0A++++return+val%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B14',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).

The short answer is yes, the compiler will most likely use NRVO.